# Cannot hide gridlines Google Spreadsheet API PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to hide all gridlines from a file I just created with Google Sheets API, I am using the following code:

```
$service = $this->GoogleServiceSheets();
$sheetID = null;
$worksheetSheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($fileID)->sheets;
foreach($worksheetSheets as $sheet){ 
    $sheetID = $sheet->properties['sheetId'];     
    break;
}
$service = $this->GoogleServiceSheets(); 

$requests = [
    new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateDimensionProperties' => [
            'range'=> new \Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionRange([
                'sheetId' => $sheetID,
                'dimension' => 'COLUMNS',
                'startIndex' => 0,
                'endIndex' => 1000        
            ]),
            'properties'=> new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionProperties([
                "hideGridlines"=> True,                 
            ]),
            'fields' => 'hideGridlines'
        ]
    ])
];



$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

But does not hide, instead gives me an error.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide the grid line of the Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API, UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest of batchUpdate is used. Unfortunately, `updateDimensionProperties` cannot achieve this. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In order to achieve your goal, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `$requests` is modified as follows.

```
$requests = [
    new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateSheetProperties' => [
            'properties' => [
                'sheetId' => $sheetID,
                'gridProperties' => [
                    'hideGridlines' => true
                ],
            ],
            'fields' => 'gridProperties.hideGridlines'
        ],
    ])
];
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `$service = $this->GoogleServiceSheets();` and `$sheetID` are valid values. And also, it supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)